Why Can't I Use AWS SSO Without a [default] Profile?
I want to use AWS Rekognition for a personal project. I downloaded the photo-asset-manager example code to get started. I also wanted to use SSO with the AWS Identity Center.
This is where I am running into issues. I'm expecting AWS to use the credentials specified by the profile that I provide on the command line.
The first step to running the example code is to create the resources for the project. For this purpose, I created a user with full access to CloudFormation. I then ran the following command:
aws configure sso

That generated the following ~/.aws/config file:
 [profile CloudFormationFullAccess-048251071589]

    sso_session = dev

    sso_account_id = xxxxxxxxxxxx

    sso_role_name = CloudFormationFullAccess

    region = us-east-1

    output = yaml

    [sso-session dev]

    sso_start_url = https://d-9067dcb33c.awsapps.com/start/

    sso_region = us-east-1

    sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access

With that I ran the following commands:
aws sso login --sso-session dev

cdk --profile CloudFormationFullAccess-048251071589 ls

That resulted in the following error: Error: Region is missing
I'm not sure where to provide that, but if I load it into my environment, e.g. export AWS_REGION=us-east-1 and rerun, I get the following error:
CredentialsProviderError: Could not load credentials from any providers
I'm stymied here, so I decided to try modifying the code that obtains the cloud formation client. The original code looks like this:
const cfnClient = new CloudFormationClient({});

I changed it to:
import {fromSSO} from "@aws-sdk/credential-providers";

const cfnClient = new CloudFormationClient({
    credentials: fromSSO({clientConfig: {region: 'us-east-1'}})
});

Re-running the code results in:
CredentialsProviderError: Profile default was not found.
OK, so I modified my config to look like this (duplicated the profile and gave it the name [default]):
[profile CloudFormationFullAccess-048251071589]

sso_session = dev

sso_account_id = xxxxxxxxxxxx

sso_role_name = CloudFormationFullAccess

region = us-east-1

output = yaml

[sso-session dev]

sso_start_url = https://d-9067dcb33c.awsapps.com/start/

sso_region = us-east-1

sso_registration_scopes = sso:account:access

[default]

sso_session = dev

sso_account_id = xxxxxxxxxxxx

sso_role_name = CloudFormationFullAccess

region = us-east-1

output = yaml

I can now run the code with success. Note that it is also successful if I remove AWS_REGION from my environment. Also note that if I revert back to the original code, it is successful, too.
My question is: Why do I have to specify a [default] profile in my config file? This goes against all the documentation that I have read on the subject. I would prefer to not have to specify a default profile. Why does it ignore the --profile that I pass on the command line?
Thanks.

I am facing a similar issue with console sign-in, https://mycompany.awsapps.com/login/ is loading an error "Connection Error
We were unable to reach the authentication server. Please try again."
